# Transitive reduction from a linear extension of a partial order

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, partial-ordering

Is there an efficient algorithm to create a [transitive reduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_reduction) from a single [linear extension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_extension) of a partial order?

**Update:** Actually, the partial order is known. I'm also aware of the [time complexity of computing a transitive reduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_reduction#Computational_complexity) of a given partial order. What I wanted to know is: given a partial order **and** one of its linear extensions, can that time complexity be reduced?

Comment: Since there can be a common linear extension for several partial orders with different transitive reductions, this is not possible - assuming what you want is find the transitive reduction of a partial order, given only one of its linear extensions.

Comment: More concretely, how would you as a human solve the problem when (1) the hidden partial order is total (2) the hidden partial order is everywhere undefined.

Comment: So just to avoid confusion: Given an input relation `R`, computation of the transitive reduction can be done via topological sorting? Furthermore, the question is specifically if the problem gets computationally easier if a linear extension of `R` is given as part of the input?

Comment: Yes, my question is: does the problem gets computationally easier if a linear extension of R is additionally given as part of the input? But, computation of the transitive reduction of R cannot be done by topological sorting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Asymptotically speaking, the answer is no. There's a trivial lower bound of Omega(n + m) just from having to examine the whole input, and topological sorting yields a linear extension in time O(n + m), which adds no asymptotic cost to any correct algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the question right, the linear extension of a partial ordering can be generated by using a [topological sorting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting) in time linear in the encoding length of the input. Following the link in your question, the generated sequence would already be a transitive reduction of itself, as its transitive closure is the same reachability relation. However, note that the linear extension of the initial partial order might not be uniquely determined.

Comment: A transitive reduction of a partial order need not be a linear order, which every topological order is.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, however I am confused about the notions. The topological sorting is a linear extension of its input, which is a total order, isn't it?

Comment: It is, but the way I understand the question is: your input is a linear extension of some (unknown) partial order, and what Martin wants to compute is a transitive reduction of the partial order.

Comment: So you understand the question as 'Given a linear extension E of some partial order (which is not explicitly given) P, compute the transitive reduction of P'?

Comment: Yes, that's how I understand it. What's your interpretation?

Comment: Apparently my interpretation made no sense. I read it as 'Given some partial order P, compute a linear extension E and a transitive reduction of E' (where the last step is not necessary).

Comment: I made an update to my question and hope it better explains what I'm looking for.